# Azure "Create SQL Database" servers not listed in "Select a server" drop-down

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

In the Azure Portal, using my Visual Studio Professional Subscription I've created both a Windows 2012 Server R2-Datacenter Virtual Machine and a Windows 2016 Server Datacenter Virtual Machine.  I've made sure they are running.  When I go to create a SQL Database, neither server is available in the "Select a server" drop-down.  Has anyone else encountered this?

[Create SQL Server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0aD0.png)

Please see the image which should help to visualize the problem.

None of my servers are ever available in the drop-down.  I can however click "Create new" and create a whole new server with SQL Server on it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "when I go to create a SQL Database"? Do you mean the SQL DB service? (if so, that has nothing to do with your VMs). What server dropdown are you referring to? Please edit your question to be specific. But... I suspect this question might be more suitable for ServerFault (it's not programming-related, and seems to be more about VM configuration).

Comment: what happens if you type in `localhost` as the server and try to connect?

Comment: FYI (based on your edit) - you've mixed "Windows Server" with "SQL Database Server" - these are unrelated to each other. SQL Database is a *service* and requires you to create a server within its service (and a server within the SQL DB service is unrelated to Windows VMs that you create)

Comment: Thanks!  I think that explains it.  I'm kind of new on here and not sure how this all works, but if you want to post your comment as an answer, then I'll mark it as the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented below the question: You've mixed "Windows Server" with "SQL Database Server" - these are unrelated to each other.

SQL Database is database-as-a-service and requires you to create a server within its service, for the database(s) you create within the service.

A server within the SQL DB service is unrelated to any Windows VMs that you create outside of the service. You won't see any Windows VMs listed within the SQL DB Service "server" dropdown, since those VMs are not managed by the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL database on Azure by Two ways as mentioned below:

1. You can either install SQL server on the VM's that you have already created (IaaS)
2. Create an Azure SQL database (PaaS) without the need for any VM

Comment: Not quite sure what's happening here, but this answer (which doesn't really answer the OP's question) turned into a documentation post (which I rolled back). FYI if someone wants to post something significantly different to what you posted, let them post their own answer. The proposed edit was a doc/link dump with 4x the amount of content as your original answer. And still didn't actually answer anything - the OP has a vague question (which I asked for clarification on, w/still no response). And if it really is about confusion of SQL DB... then it's a doc issue. Not a programming one.